# A Hosted Spring MVC and mySql Application Sometimes Generates Server Disconnection Error

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I developed a spring MVC application that interacts with mySql and when I was satisfied that it was working 100% of the time locally on my own computer I put it online using a hosting service. However, I've had nothing but problems and am trying to work out if the source is my code or a problem with the host.

Sometimes my application works fine, and at other times I get a **http status 500 internal server error**  so that would lead me to believe that the problem is with the host and not my application.

Unfortuneatly the error is saved as a pdf that I can't upload to your site but it says the problem is:
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: communications link failure**

Please note that on this hosting site I have my own private tomcat server. Also, I use connection pooling to connect to the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry, I also get the following error message at the bottom of the error 500 page:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost

Comment: 500 IS an application error.  Add logging and go from there.

Comment: Sorry, I also get the following error at the bottom of the error 500 page: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost

Comment: You have to track down where the error is happening in your code specifically.  The errors you are sharing are Java class error, but most likely your code caused these errors, you need a full stack trace.